# Determining the JRE of an IBM Liberty server

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I would like to determine the JRE of my Liberty server. Is there a simple command that I can use to do this?

Comment: I will assume that means no.

Comment: Well gets me what is in the path at least. will try that version and see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

./bin/server version

It will show you what version of liberty is running, as well as which version of the JDK/JRE the server is configured to use.

The output (I'm on a mac), would look something like this:

WebSphere Application Server 8.5.x.x (1.0.x.xxxxxxxxxx) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 (en_US)

Comment: Thank you ebullient. This works great on Red Hat too.